# Laravel 8 passport installation failed

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-8

I tried installing laravel/passport by running `composer require laravel/passport` and it gives me error saying :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



Problem 1
    - lcobucci/jwt 4.2.x-dev requires ext-sodium * -> the requested PHP extension sodium is missing from your system.
    - lcobucci/jwt 4.1.x-dev requires ext-sodium * -> the requested PHP extension sodium is missing from your system.
    - lcobucci/jwt 4.1.0 requires ext-sodium * -> the requested PHP extension sodium is missing from your system.
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v10.1.0
    - Conclusion: remove lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[10.x-dev, v10.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3
    - laravel/passport 10.x-dev requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.x-dev, 4.0.0, 4.0.0-alpha1, 4.0.0-alpha2, 4.0.0-alpha3, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.0.1, 4.0.x-dev, 4.1.0, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[3.4.0, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[3.4.1, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[3.4.2, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[3.4.3, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[3.4.x-dev, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.0, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.0-alpha1, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.0-alpha2, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.0-alpha3, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.0-beta1, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.1, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: lcobucci/jwt[4.0.x-dev, 3.3.3].
    - Installation request for lcobucci/jwt (locked at 3.3.3) -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I saw some solution in SO saying adding some version to the laravel/passport like so : `composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1`, but I'm not confident if this works with laravel 8

Answer (score 4):

you can uncomment the "sodium" extension in the php.ini file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while deploying a Laravel app into EC2 AMI2 as OS. I was I just installed ext-sodium using:

```
sudo yum install php-sodium
```

Answer (score 3):

> Just Delete the composer.lock file and run `composer install` command
> again. Don't forget to thanks me :)

Most of Cases, Issue generate by composer lock file so delete it before setup the project

Comment: doing this did not remove the "ext-sodium" requirement for me

Answer (score 1):

> Problem 1
>
> > - lcobucci/jwt 4.2.x-dev requires ext-sodium * -> the requested PHP extension sodium is missing from your system.

it looks like extension:sodium is commented in your php.ini file
goto your php.ini file and uncomment it , then reload your apache if you use xampp then try to run composer again

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to fix it `composer require laravel/passport --with-all-dependencies` this will  allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34655673)